# Add a list of dates as an image properties in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: landsat, modis, google-earth-engine, time-series

I've merged two image collections after calculating median values by month in each collection from 2000 to 2018. However I need to carry out an operation that needs the "sytem:time.start" field that was lost after calculating the monthly means. Therefore, I would like to know how to add a property within each image of the collection from a list representing month and year? The only property I have now in my collection is "system:index".

The code can be accessed by [this link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/632c17f524ff479737ac8797d2424632). 
The collection I want to associate with "system:time.start" information is on line 164, named "joined_collections"